I am facing issue regarding the armstrong number in assembly language for 8086. the code works in the range 0 to 9 but I want it for 3 digit number
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
msg1 db "Enter a 3-digit number: $"
msg2 db "Armstrong number!"
msg3 db "Not an Armstrong number!"
notValid db "Please enter a 3-digit number (100-999): $"
numStr db 10 dup('$')   ; String to store user input (10 characters)
num dw 0               ; Integer to store converted number

.code

main proc
  mov ax, @data
  mov ds, ax

  mov dx, offset msg1
  mov ah, 09h
  int 21h

  ; Read user input as a string
  mov ah, 0Ah
  mov dx, offset numStr
  int 21h

  ; Check if the input length is 3
  mov cx, 0
  loop_check:
    mov bl, [numStr + cx]
    cmp bl, '$'
    je check_done  ; Reached end of string
    inc cx
    jmp loop_check

  check_done:
  cmp cx, 3
  jne not_valid  ; Not a 3-digit number

  ; Convert string to integer (assuming digits only)
  mov si, offset numStr
  mov di, offset num
  mov cx, 0
loop_convert:
    mov al, [si]
    sub al, 30h     ; Convert ASCII digit to integer
    mov [di], ax
    inc si
    inc di
    loop loop_convert

  ; Process the number as before (unchanged)
  mov ax, num
  xor cx, cx
  xor bx, bx
  mov dx, 10

l1:
  div dx
  add bx, dx
  inc cx
  cmp ax, 0
  jne l1

  cmp bx, num
  jne not_armstrong

  mov dx, offset msg2
  mov ah, 09h
  int 21h
  jmp exit

not_armstrong:
  mov dx, offset msg3
  mov ah, 09h
  int 21h

exit:
  ret

main endp
end main

I tried by reading multiple digits from user but can;t worked.

Please [edit] your post to add content above the code that explains what the code is supposed to do ("Armstrong number* is not enough - we don't want to have to google to find out what that is),  the problem that you're having, and to include a specific question that can be answered. Also, you'll find that your experiences here will be much better if you take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting. I'd suggest special attention be paid to [ask].

A two digit number, ab, as digits, has value of a×10+b. I don't see any of that in rhe code.

@ErikEidt:  Displaying numbers with DOS is the canonical Q&A for how to print multi-digit integers with DOS, if you're looking for something to link.  But detecting Armstrong numbers already requires breaking them into (decimal) digits so you should just save that result to avoid having to repeat it if it is an Armstrong number.

Armstrong number / Narcissistic number
Is a number that is the sum of its own digits each raised to the power of the number of digits.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number
In above case (100 - 999) we search for 3-digit numbers. There are exact 4 possible results.
153 = 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3

370 = 3^3 + 7^3 + 0^3

371 = 3^3 + 7^3 + 1^3

407 = 4^3 + 0^3 + 7^3


MASM assembles op's code but instruction mov bl, [numStr + cx] is interpreted as mov bh, [bx + si + 00D6], 8A B8 D6 00.
Other cases:
mov ax,10h
mov bl, [numStr + ax]   ; mov bl, [00D6]            8A 1E D6 00

mov bx,10h
mov bl, [numStr + bx]   ; mov bl, [bx + 00D6]       8A 9F D6 00

mov cx,10h
mov bl, [numStr + cx]   ; mov bh, [bx + si + 00D6]  8A B8 D6 00 

mov dx,10h
mov bl, [numStr + dx]   ; mov bh, [bx + si + 00D6]  8A B8 D6 00 

mov sp,10h
mov bl, [numStr + sp]   ; mov bh, [bx + si + 00D6]  8A B8 D6 00 

mov bp,10h
mov bl, [numStr + bp]   ; mov bl, [bp + 00D6]       8A 9E D6 00

mov si,10h
mov bl, [numStr + si]   ; mov bl, [si + 00D6]       8A 9C D6 00

mov di,10h
mov bl, [numStr + di]   ; mov bl, [di + 00D6]       8A 9D D6 00

TASM shows error Illegal indexing mode.
Also label not_valid doesn't exist in above code.

Solution:

First we want to check how many characters user entered.
This information is stored under offset numStr + 1. This is how service ah = 0ah, int 21h works.
First byte numStr is maximum number of characters + 0dh (CR)
Second byte numStr + 1 is all characters without 0dh (CR)
Third byte numStr + 2 is beginning of the buffer
In the code above numStr contains 10 x '$' = 24h = 36 so this is not good.
I changed this to numStr db 4, ?, 4 dup('$')
First byte,  max 4 chars  = 3 digits + 0dh
Second byte, ?            = after pressing enter this byte contains max number of values
Third byte,  4 dup('$')   = start of the buffer





Next I added code which checks if characters entered are only digits and number doesn't start with 0.



loop_convert should convert digits from buffer to integer but calculations are wrong because si doesn't contain offset to buffer.
Also ax has some wierd values.

Code:
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    msg1 db "Enter a 3-digit number: $"
    msg2 db "Armstrong number!",13,10,'$'
    msg3 db "Not an Armstrong number!",13,10,'$'
    msg4 db "Not enough digits in the buffer, we need 3 digits!",13,10,'$'
    msg5 db "Number in buffer starts with 0.",13,10,'$' 
    msg6 db "Characters in the buffer are not digits.",13,10,'$'        
    
    numStr db 4,?, 4 dup('$')    ; String to store user input (3 characters + 0dh (CF))
    num dw 0                     ; Integer to store converted number

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov dx, offset msg1
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Read user input as a string
    mov ah, 0Ah
    mov dx, offset numStr
    int 21h

    ; Check if the input length is 3
  
    mov dl, [numStr + 1]  
    cmp dl, 3           
    je digits_in_the_buffer
    jmp buffer_msg

    ; search for buffer errors

    digits_in_the_buffer:
        mov cx, 3                   ; check 3 digits
        mov si, offset numStr       ; digits are stored here
        add si, 2
        push si                     ; save buffer offset
        
        cmp byte ptr [si], '0'      ; first character in the buffer can't be 0  
        je first_char_is_zero
        
        check_characters:           ; all characters should be digits
            cmp byte ptr [si], '0'          
            jb wrong_char
            cmp byte ptr [si], '9'
            ja wrong_char
            
            inc si
            dec cx          
            jnz check_characters
            
    ; Convert string to integer 
    
    chars_in_the_buffer_ok:         ; number ok
        pop si                      ; restore buffer offset  
        mov cx, 2
        mov bl, 10                  
        xor ax, ax
        xor dx, dx

        mov al, [si]                ; first digits from buffer
        sub al, '0'                 ; Convert ASCII digit to integer
        
        loop_convert:
            mul bl                  ; 8bit multiplication, result is in ax
            inc si
            mov dl, [si]
            sub dl, '0'
            add al, dl          
            adc ah, 0        ; Only important on the 2nd (last) iteration 
            dec cx      
            jnz loop_convert

    mov [num], ax

    mov dx, offset msg2             ; print new line
    add dx, 17          
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    sub si, 2                       ; return to start of the buffer
    
    ; armstrong number
    
    armstrong_number:
        mov dx, 3                   ; outer loop counter for each digit
        xor di, di                  ; result will be stored in di
        xor bx, bx
        
        process_digit:
            xor ax, ax
            mov al, [si]            ; digit from buffer
            sub al, '0'         
            mov bl, al              

            mov cx, 2               ; inner loop counter
            
            inner_loop:
                mul bl              ; calculate power of each digit 
                
                dec cx
                jnz inner_loop
            
            add di, ax              
            
            inc si

            dec dx
            jnz process_digit


        cmp di, word ptr [num]      
        jnz not_armstrong 

        mov dx, offset msg2         ; if armstrong number print hooray msg
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
        jmp exit_app

    ; error messages

    not_armstrong:                  ; else quit app
        mov dx, offset msg3
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
        jmp exit_app 
    
    first_char_is_zero:
        mov dx, offset msg5
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
        jmp exit_app

    wrong_char:
        mov dx, offset msg6
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
        jmp exit_app

    buffer_msg:
        mov dx, offset msg4
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h

    exit_app:
        mov ax,4c00h
        int 21h

main endp
end main


An error I have corrected: loop_convert forgot the potential carry on the add al, dl instruction. An optimization that is up to you: inner_loop can do better with mul bl that doesn't clobber DX. You could then use DX for your outer loop counter and don't need to push cx / pop cx.

MASM assembles mov bl, [numStr + cx]?  What a bad assembler; that's not a valid 16-bit addressing mode!  That's a nasty assembler bug; good assemblers like NASM print an error message instead of turning it into a different addressing mode.  Doesn't MASM at least warn?

@PeterCordes No warnings, nothing. I used ml /c file.asm. Then I tried with /WX - Treat warnigs as errors and /W<number> - Set warning level. Same story. I checked with other 16 bit regs cx, dx, sp generates same opcodes 8A B8 D6 00.

Wow.  That's an assembler bug.  What version of MASM are you using?  Something 30 years old, or a current version?  If it's current, you could report it to MS so they can fix it (report an error instead of silently assembling it with the r/m field = 0 when there's no encoding for the registers requested.)

I tried masm 6.11 and 6.14.8444 versions. I discovered this bug during assembling op's code.
